# laravel query OR in join tables part

Tags: laravel

I need help.

```
$ham_liste = DB::table('akis')
                ->join('lisansli_yapim', 'lisansli_yapim.saytek_id', '=', 'akis.ProgID')
                ->select('progAdi', 'akis.Aciklama', 'akis.bolum', 'gosterim_hakki', 'gosterim_sayisi', 'tarihi', 'saat')
                ->orderBy('progAdi')
                ->orderBy('bolum')
                ->orderBy('tarihi')
                ->orderBy('saat')
                ->get();
```

how can i add second parameter on join part with OR key.

```
('lisansli_yapim', 'lisansli_yapim.saytek_id', '=', 'akis.ProgID')
```

or

```
('lisansli_yapim', 'lisansli_yapim.saytek_id_2', '=', 'akis.ProgID')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a closure to `join` and then use `orOn`:

```
$ham_liste = DB::table('akis')
            ->join('lisansli_yapim', function ($join) {
                $join->on('lisansli_yapim.saytek_id', '=', 'akis.ProgID');
                $join->orOn('lisansli_yapim.saytek_id_2', '=', 'akis.ProgID');
            })
            ->select('progAdi', 'akis.Aciklama', 'akis.bolum', 'gosterim_hakki', 'gosterim_sayisi', 'tarihi', 'saat')
            ->orderBy('progAdi')
            ->orderBy('bolum')
            ->orderBy('tarihi')
            ->orderBy('saat')
            ->get();
```

See the [advanced join clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins) section for more information.